# Simplest way to save persistent data on android (BroadcastReceiver)

Tags: android

I need to save one `int` in a persistent manner.

The simplest way i found is : `SharedPreferences` but it requires activity, i don't have an activity because I inherited from BroadcastReciever and want to save and read the data in

```
public void onReceive(final Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
{
  // Save data here
}
```

What is my best and simplest option.

Comment: why `SharedPreferences` not working? `SharedPreferences` required `context` and you already have it.

Comment: SharedPreferences do not need an Activity. It needs a context. Activity, Service and even Context is a context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the context in `onReceive`. So it's easy:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent arg1) 
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 
                                                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("key_name", "string value");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences are related to a Context, not an Activity, so you could use

```
public void onReceive(final Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
{
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(arg0).edit().putInt(yourInt).apply();
}
```